# Checking multiple condition values does not output the else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am attempting to check a list of zip codes and then assign the variable `zipAssign` a value based on if the zip code entered matches one from the list.

In the codes current state it always displays "AB".

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$('#salesforce_submit').change(function () {
  //Find AB Zip Code
  var zipVal = '';
  var zipAssign = '';
  zipVal = $('#zip').val();
  if (zipVal = 44030 || 44048 || 44082 || 44003 || 44093 || 44076 || 44062 || 44021 || 44046 || 44099 || 44032 || 44047 || 44010 || 44057 || 44086 || 44064 || 44024 || 44023 || 44065 || 44022 || 44072 || 44040 || 44143 || 44094 || 44139 || 44146 || 44128 || 44105 || 44122 || 44124 || 44121 || 44117 || 44108 || 44110 || 44103 || 44106 || 44118 || 44120 || 44104 || 44114 || 44127 || 44125 || 44131 || 44134 || 44129 || 44130 || 44144 || 44109 || 44115 || 44136 || 44133 || 44147 || 44141 || 44067 || 44056 || 44087 || 44195) { 
   zipAssign = 'AB';
  } else {
   zipAssign = '';
  }
  console.log(zipAssign);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="salesforce_submit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div><input id="zip" placeholder="Zip/Postal Code*" class="input block" maxlength="6" name="zip" type="text" pattern= "[0-9]{5}"></div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the codes current state it always displays "AB".
>
> Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

because `zipVal = 44030 || 44048` will always return a truthy value.

Create an array of `zipVals` and use `includes`

```
var zipVals = [ 44030 , 44048 , 44082 , 44003 , 44093 , 44076 , 44062 , 44021 , 44046 , 44099 , 44032 , 44047 , 44010 , 44057 , 44086 , 44064 , 44024 , 44023 , 44065 , 44022 , 44072 , 44040 , 44143 , 44094 , 44139 , 44146 , 44128 , 44105 , 44122 , 44124 , 44121 , 44117 , 44108 , 44110 , 44103 , 44106 , 44118 , 44120 , 44104 , 44114 , 44127 , 44125 , 44131 , 44134 , 44129 , 44130 , 44144 , 44109 , 44115 , 44136 , 44133 , 44147 , 44141 , 44067 , 44056 , 44087 , 44195 ];

    if ( zipVals.includes( +zipVal ) ) {    //convert zipVal to a number before using includes
        zipAssign = 'AB';
    } else {
        zipAssign = '';
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and it threw the error of `zipVal` not being defined, so I put in `var zipVal = ''`, but not it just always displays null.

Comment: Zipval is the same value you get from input box

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't do that.

This is what you are looking for: `if (zipVal === 44030 || zipVal === 44048 || etc...)`

However, another option is to create an array of all the zipCodes and then check your condition  with `if (myArray.includes(zipVal))`

Comment: `=` should be `==`

Answer (score 2):

1. When checking equality, you need to write `==` or `===` instead of `=`: `zipVal == 44030`.
2. When you want to compare the same variable against multiple values, you still have to write out all the conditions: `zipVal == 44030 || zipVal == 44048 || (etc.)`

Note however that this is not a good way to check if a value is in a set of values this large. Instead, you should collect the ZIP codes in an array:

```
var zipCodes = [ 44030, 44084, (etc.) ]
```

And then just use `.includes()`:

```
if (zipCodes.includes(zipVal)) {
    zipAssign = 'AB';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you just made a small mistake, instead of comparing (==) two value, you assigned one to another (=) in the if condition.

Here I recreated you code.

```js
$('#salesforce_submit').change(function () {
  //Find AB Zip Code
  var zipVal = '';
  var zipAssign = '';
  zipVal = $('#zip').val();
  if (zipVal == 44030 || zipVal == 44048 || zipVal == 44082 || zipVal == 44003 || zipVal == 44093 || zipVal == 44076 || zipVal == 44062 || zipVal == 44021 || zipVal == 44046 || zipVal == 44099 || zipVal == 44032 || zipVal == 44047 || zipVal == 44010 || zipVal == 44057 || zipVal == 44086 || zipVal == 44064 || 44024 || 44023 || 44065 || 44022 || 44072 || 44040 || 44143 || 44094 || zipVal == 44139 || zipVal == 44146 || zipVal == 44128 || zipVal == 44105 || zipVal == 44122 || zipVal == 44124 || zipVal == 44121 || zipVal == 44117 || zipVal == 44108 || zipVal == 44110 || zipVal == 44103 || zipVal == 44106 || zipVal == 44118 || zipVal == 44120 || zipVal == 44104 || zipVal == 44114 || zipVal == 44127 || zipVal == 44125 || zipVal == 44131 || zipVal == 44134 || zipVal == 44129 || zipVal == 44130 || zipVal == 44144 || zipVal == 44109 || zipVal == 44115 || zipVal == 44136 || zipVal == 44133 || zipVal == 44147 || zipVal == 44141 || zipVal == 44067 || zipVal == 44056 || zipVal == 44087 || zipVal == 44195) { 
   zipAssign = 'AB';
  } else {
   zipAssign = '';
  }
  console.log(zipAssign);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="salesforce_submit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div><input id="zip" placeholder="Zip/Postal Code*" class="input block" maxlength="6" name="zip" type="text" pattern= "[0-9]{5}"></div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But I strongly suggest to create an array of ZIP code and loop it with the input value for comparing.

I hope this will help you. Thank you.

Comment: That's not how the `||` operator works. The expression `(44030 || 44048 || 44082 || (etc.)` will just evaluate to the first truthy value, in this case 44030.